# ¿Problemas al hacer un composer update en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, script, composer

Estoy encontrando un problema demasiado raro, estoy trabajando con laravel 5.2, tengo la versión de php 7.2, cuando hago el comando "composer update" me aparece un error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.6.*",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "appzcoder/crud-generator": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "dnetix/redirection": "^0.4.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Banco2\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": { 
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Pero en lo que colocas no hay error. Dice **Nothing to install or update** porque efectivamente no tienes algún paquete actualizable a una nueva versión ni un paquete nuevo para instalar. Puedes seguir programando tu app en Laravel tranquilamente.